# How can achieve uniform column content spacing with Bootstrap's grid?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

i am trying to set a few elements with different types - in one row using Bootstrap, problem is the spaces are aligned incorrectly.... suppose i'm using the grid system, how can i tweak the spaces between the elements?

Thanks!

```
  <div class="row">

  <div class="col-md-2">
  <p class="box-title custom_spacing">Banner List</p>
  </div>
 <div class="col-md-2">
  <p class="box-title custom_spacing">Filtering Options</p>
 </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
 <select class="form-control selectpicker">
 <option class="op"></option>
</select>
 </div>
<div class="col-md-6">
<input type="text">
</div>
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/roybarak/h29ypw47/3/#&togetherjs=fAR0cxSJfh)

Comment: I don't think it's presently clear what your desired layout is, and how your current one doesn't match it. Can you describe in detail what you're trying to achieve here?

Comment: I guess spacing..... the alignment is fine as it, the spaces are my problem... i'm looking for a way to tweak it - within bootstrap...

Comment: If you're just talking about the space between columns (aka. Gutter widths), these can be modified if you're familiar with CSS preprocessors. There's some helpful information on this in the Bootstrap documentation.

Comment: Got it ! Here is the trick https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F5izCKASMDs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be cumbersome and awkward to try and customize spacing between grid column contents, especially in a responsive site. Instead, use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) (if [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) is acceptable), or center an inline list in a single column.